# DML statistics, oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Does oracle (11g at least, but it would be nice if 10g too) have some statistics on DML been performed?

What I expect to get is: `for table A in schema B it was performed I inserts, J updates, K deletes from date1 to date2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `monitoring` feature and the `dba_tab_modifications` table to get that information. See for example [here](http://oracle-apps-dba.blogspot.com/2007/07/monitoring-dml-operations.html) or [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/bk_dba_tab_modifications.htm).